# Creating arrays in C++ without knowing the length ahead of time

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm working on a small program to help speed up some data analysis for my lab work. It's supposed to read in data from a text file, create a bunch of arrays containing this data and then do some maths.

The problem I keep running into is that I don't know how many lines the original text file will have, so I don't know how big to make my arrays. I'm very new to C++ and right now I don't feel comfortable with dynamically sized arrays, here's a bit of the code

```
// first determine the length of the file
ifstream dataFile ("xys_data.txt");
const int LENGTH = count(istreambuf_iterator<char>(dataFile), istreambuf_iterator<char>(), '\n'); // counts the number of new lines

// declare vector of type datapoint
dataPoint data[LENGTH];
```

When I try and compile this i get the error

```
expected constant expression
cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
'data' : unknown size
```

But haven't I defined the LENGTH to be constant?

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Following the advice of almost all of you, I have started using std::vector. I have one last issue that I'm a bit shaky on.

In the first attempt at the program I defined a data structure:

```
struct dataPoint
{
  double x; // x values
  double y; // y values
  double s; // sigma values
};
```

Then when I read the data from the file, I sent it to this structure like so

```
while (!dataFile.eof()) // this loop writes out each row of data to the arrays x, y, s until it reaches the end of the file
{ 
  int j = 0;
  dataFile >> data[j].x >> data[j].y >> data[j].s;
  j++;
}
```

Is there a way I can do this using vectors? My first thought is to define the vectors x, y and s and replace the `data[j].x` with `x` in the loop, but this doesn't work.

Comment: Use `std::vector`.

Comment: It must be a compile time constant, like `constexpr` in C++11. A simple `const` doesn't work (although most modern compiles allow for var arrays in C++), as the value of your `const` is determined at runtime. So use a `std::vector`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter just realized that and was editing actually :) thanks anyway.

Comment: Counting the number of lines will not work, and where you define LENGTH, count is returning 0 at some point. You can set a buffer, like, data[1024], as long as you know that there wont be overflow.

Comment: As @JonathanPotter already said, just use `std::vector`. Learning to use it will be *much* easier (even in the short run, and even more so in the long run) than trying to patch something together something else.

Comment: prefer to use std::vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First and foremost, built in arrays in C++ have to have compile-time size. It is not enough to declare your `LENGTH` variable `const`. It is also important to make it a compile-time constant. Your `LENGTH` is not a compile time constant, so declaring an array of size `LENGTH` is not possible. This is what the compiler is trying to tell you.

When you need to build an array, whose size is not known in advance, you typically have at least three approaches to choose from:

1. **Two-pass reading.** Make a "dry run" over the data source to determine the exact size of the future array. Allocate the array. Make a second pass over the data source to fill the array with data.
2. **Reallocation.** Use a reallocatable array. Allocate an array of some fixed size and fill it with data. If the array proves to be too small, reallocate it to bigger size and continue to fill it. Continue to read and reallocate until all data is read.
3. **Conversion.** Read the data into a cheaply and easily expandable data structure (like linked list), then convert it to array.

Each of these approaches has it own pros and cons, limitations and areas of applicability.

It looks like in your case you are trying to use the first approach. It is not a very good idea to use it when you are working with files. Firstly, making two passes over a file is not very efficient. Secondly, in general case it might create a race condition: the file might change between the passes. If you still want to go that way, just use `std::vector` instead of a built-in array.

However, in your case I would recommend using the second approach. Again, use `std::vector` to store your data. Read your data line by line and append it to the vector, item by item. The vector will automatically reallocate itself as necessary.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on method 2 please? Specifically how would I append the data to the vector? Right now what I'm doing is sending the data to a data structure like so
    while (!dataFile.eof()) // this loop writes out each row of data to the arrays x, y, s until it reaches the end of the file
    { 
      int j = 0;
      dataFile >> data[j].x >> data[j].y >> data[j].s;
      j++;
    }

Comment: Oh I didn't know that comments can't be formatted, i'll make an edit in the OP

Comment: @user78655: Well, naturally. You read a single line into a local `dataPoint data;` object, as in `dataFile >> data.x >> data.y >> data.s;` and then do `vector.push_back(data);`. Repeat until you read the whole file.

Answer (score 3):

You say that you're not comfortable with dynamically-sized arrays, or `std::vector`.

I'm afraid that you'll have to figure out how to get comfortable here, because that's precisely what's `std::vector` is for.

The only other alternative is to use the `gcc` compiler. `gcc` does allow you to have variable-sized arrays. It's a compiler extension, it's not standard C or C++:

```
void method(size_t n)
{
   dataPoint array[n];

   // Do something with the array.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either use a C++ container, like [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), or use `dataPoint *data = malloc(LENGTH * sizeof(dataPoint))`. In C++, it's probably better practice to use `std::vector`.

C99 has [variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), but you're question seems to be C++.

The real problem, though, is that you want to slurp the whole file all at once. Unless you're using a library that requires data to be in memory, it'll probably be easier to iterate over the text of the file using [`fgetc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetc/) or whatever C++ has for that. After all, you'll need to go through the text at some point; you might as well save yourself the trouble of allocating memory.

Comment: With your malloc() suggestion, doesn't that require knowing the length of the "data"?

Comment: `// first determine the length of the file` suggests to me that they've already figured that out.

Comment: Scratch that, he's counting lines not bytes.

Comment: If you _must_, use `new` not `malloc`. Seriously, WTH?!